# Excel Function to find first name and Last name of a person for Kudos

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to track First name and Last name of a person in comments from a survey using an excel function?

I want the function to work for any first name and last name.

Here is what I have tried?

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"*Any first Name*","*Any Last Name*"}))
```

- I am using Count cells with multiple criteria (OR logic)

Comment: what do you get with that formula, a wrong count, an error,...?

Comment: What does your data look like? Parsing first and last names might [prove harder than you think](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: BTW, OR logic is a little bit misleading.  The COUNTIFS will be run twice, once for the first name and again for the second.  What that means is that if the column has both the first and last name it will count as 2 not 1.

Comment: My data is consist of comments from a survey conducted; within the survey names are mentioned and I wanted to see if the names are mentioned in a positive way or negative way. The survey also has the sentiments(Negative, neutral, and Neutral) besides each comments. @BruceWayne

Comment: @ScottCraner That's the trouble I am having now using the OR logic because some comments might have the first name and not last name and vice versa. It is tricky.

Comment: so you are getting larger number than you expect?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"*Any first Name*","*Any Last Name*"})) -COUNTIFS(A:A,"*Any first Name*",A:A,"*Any Last Name*")` This way it removes `1` when both are present and the first part add `2`.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes I am getting Larger numbers than expected so should I try the function you gave me?

Comment: Yes, try that one.  It will adjust if both first and last are found in the comment

Comment: @ScottCraner I believe that did it, I appreciate it. It seems like regardless if one or the other is in comment, it counts it.

Comment: @ScottCraner How would you go about making sure it is looking for the exact name(first name and last name) specified?

Comment: @ScottCraner how do I limit it to detect only the first name and last name specified? What I am finding is that if the name is included in another word; it counts it .I tried using the Exact function but I am getting any luck.

Comment: add space between the `*` and the name.

Comment: @ScottCraner So like this =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"* Any first Name *","* Any Last Name *"})) -COUNTIFS(A:A,"* Any first Name *",A:A,"* Any Last Name *")